# Testing models default value

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, marionette

The model below has null for all its attributes defaults.  But when I test the attributes with Jasmines toBeNull() function it doesnt evaluate to true.  And says the attribute is undefined.  Why?
I have the following backbone model defined :

```
Entities.GroupModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: 
{
    "gid"         : null,
    "title"       : null,
    "description" : null,
    "access_date" : null
}
});
```

Then in a test  I create a new model like so...

```
var groupModel = new CCDocUploader.Entities.GroupModel({});

console.log(groupModel);  ///when I inspect the attributes i see they are set to null
console.log(groupModel.gid == null); //this evaluates to true
expect(groupModel.gid).toBeNull(); ///this claims it is undefined and fails...why?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access attributes of module directly as:

```
groupModel.gid;
```

You should use [accessors](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) instead:

```
groupModel.get('gid');
```

In your case you have `groupModel.gid == null` because `groupModel.gid` is `undefined` and in JS:

```
undefined == null // => true
null == null // => true
```